# Is this a valid proof that if $X_n \to 0$ and $X_n \geqslant 0$ for all $n$ , then $\sqrt{X_n}\to 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

This question

Prove that if $X_n \to0$ and $X_n\geqslant0$ for all $n$ , then $\sqrt{X_n}\to0$

This is my solution:

Given any $\varepsilon>0$ , $\exists n_1\in\mathbb N$ such that

$$|Xn−0|< \varepsilon ,\ ∀n\geqslant n_1$$

$−\varepsilon<X_n<\varepsilon,\ \forall n \geq n_1$

because $X_n\geqslant0$ then

$0<X_n<\varepsilon,\ \forall n \geq n_1$

When take $\surd$ for all terms  will get

$$0 <\sqrt{X_n} <\sqrt\varepsilon ,\ \forall n\geqslant n_1$$

$\left|\sqrt{X_n}−0\right|<\sqrt\varepsilon,\ \forall n\geqslant n_1$

Choose $\varepsilon=\varepsilon²$ then

$$\left|\sqrt{X_n}−0\right|<\varepsilon,\ \forall n\geqslant n_1$$

So $\sqrt{X_n}\to0$

Comment: Welcome Fatima but may you improve your post : for example : prove if $ x_n\ge0 $ and $x_n\underset{n\to +\infty}{\to}0\; \implies \sqrt{x_n}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\to}0$

Comment: It is very hard to follow you for two reasons 1) You don't say what you mean about  $X_n$ (Random Variable ?) tending to 0 (?), central limit theorem that you invoke in your tags, etc... 2) you dont use mathjax (latex)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot choose $\varepsilon=\varepsilon^2$. There are only two numbers with this property: $0$ and $1$.

Take $\varepsilon>0$. You know that there is $n_1\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\geqslant n_1\implies|X_n|<\varepsilon^2$. But then$$n\geqslant n_1\implies\sqrt{|X_n|}<\varepsilon\iff\left\vert\sqrt{X_n}\right\vert<\varepsilon.$$